# fatal error while installing apr util

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install [CACTUS](http://cactuscode.org/), but it requires APR and APR-util. I have succesfully installed APR, but with APR-util a fatal error is returned:

```
xml/apr_xml.c:35:19: fatal error: expat.h: File o directory non esistente
```

saying that the folder `xml/apr_xml` is not found.

The error occurred when I ran `make`; `./configuration` had no problems.

What do I do?

Comment: Have you installed the `libexpat1-dev` (XML parsing C library - development kit) package?

Comment: No as far as I remember. Where do I find it?

Comment: Well, there's a version in the Ubuntu main repository - I would try that first

Comment: So I should do `sudo apt install libexpat1-dev`?

Comment: Yes try that - if it doesn't work (for example, the version is too old for the software you're trying to build) then you can easily uninstall it to build a more recent version from source (not so easy the other way around)