# Error with make test installing apr-util

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install `apr-util` so I can install [CACTUS](http://cactuscode.org/). [Yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/q/1168199/743263) I could not run `make` because it didn't find some xml files. I installed the `libexpat1-dev` and the `make` ran without problems.

Today with `make test` I have the following errors:

```
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetEntityDeclHandler'
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate'
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetUserData'
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_StopParser'
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
../.libs/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
```

What do I do?

Comment: Did you re-run `./configure` after installing `libexpat1-dev`?

Comment: No I didn't run it

Comment: @steeldriver I ran again `./configure`, but now `./buildconf` says `./buildconf: 75: ./buildconf: autoheader: not found`. `make` also doesn't run anymore.

Comment: @mattiav27 Just curious, will `libaprutil1-dev` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libaprutil1-dev&searchon=names) suite your needs? For most build tools you need to install `build-essential` package, for `autoheader` you have to install `autoconf`.

Comment: @mattiav27 please indicate your Ubuntu version. You might want to try starting over and unpacking the source tarball(s) again from scratch.

Comment: @steeldriver I use 16.04

Comment: @steeldriver I have re-tried unpacking the tars from scratch, but I still get the error `./buildconf: autoheader: not found`

Comment: @steeldriver I have solved the problem using the comment of N0rbert